# "Lasting" or "with a duration of"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm editing a very bureaucratic document and I'm trying to make it less bureaucratic.
There's a passage that refers to "a session with a duration of 1-2 hours." I want to change it to "a session lasting 1-2 hours."

I don't see why that should be a problem, but it's Monday morning and I don't feel like my brain has come back from the weekend yet so I'm being cautious.

Does anyone think that is in any way confusing or less clear than the wordy "with a duration of" usage? This document is riddled with such overly wordy usages and I'm really trying to make it more readable without losing any meaning.

Comment: Sounds a reasonable enough substitution to me.

Comment: You could even go further: "a session of 1–2 hours"; "a 1–2-hour session".

Comment: Sarah, if you're charged with simplifying an entire document full of such stuffy verbosity, you might need to big up the courage of your convictions! Then go for broke! - what about globally replacing all ***sessions*** with ***meetings***, for example? (except the ones that aren't actually "meetings", but there probably won't be any! :)

Comment: Another vote here for "a 1-2 hour session".  Conveys all the information in the simplest manner.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: please make that an Answer.

Comment: I like "a 1-2 hour session" And I'm looking into session v. meeting, as this document pertains to a psychiatric setting. Thanks a lot -- I wish I'd found this site a long time ago!